# Plus sign in URL Get Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, datetimeoffset

I create Web Api

Method GET

```
[HttpGet]
[CustomBasicAuthorize]
public UpdateStatus CreateTimePost(long alarmId, int time, string clientTimeFormat)
{  
  //code  
}
```

Example of url :

```
var url =string.Format("http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:51165//api/alllarms/CreateTimePostFacebook?alarmId={0}&time={1}&clientTimeFormat={2}", id,  unixTimestamp, clienttime);
```

where `clienttime="2014-03-17T17:40:10+0200"`

But on the server I get `"3/17/2014 7:40:10 PM  02:00"`  without plus ("+")

And thats why I can't convert to correct time.

```
var clientTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse(correctString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I get error `"Incorrect datetime format"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` or `WebUtility.UrlEncode` to encode your url

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(clienttime)
```

Since `+` means a space when in url.